# Voice Memos (ios app) recording to Google Drive

Tags: ios

Is there any way to upload the Voice Memos recording to Google Drive? As far as I see it only allows you to share via Email and Message.

If not, Is there an alternative to do this?

I found this: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dictonic-voice-recorder-for/id652076268?mt=8

But I think there might be a free one.

Answer (score 2):

Send it to yourself via text. When it arrives, click on the file download icon. Save to Google Drive (must have the app already on phone).

Answer (score 0):

If you have dropbox you can save the recording onto dropbox and from your dropbox app choose open in google drive app and it will export it to google drive. I had to do this when my lecture recording was too long to send via email.